# Understanding an application of Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

I'm going over some lecture notes for a course in statistical theory. There is a "proof" that the density for a $k$-dimensional multivariate normal random variable (with non-singular covariance) is, in fact, a density. In this proof there is a line:

$$ \int \prod_{i=1}^k \phi(y_i) \, d\boldsymbol{y} = \prod_{i=1}^k \int \phi(y_i) \, dy_i \quad \textrm{(by Fubini)}$$

Where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the density function for a standard normal, $d\boldsymbol{y} = d(y_1, \ldots, y_k)$ (I suppose) indicates integration with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $dy_i$ indicates integration with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

My understanding of product spaces is a little weak and I'm struggling to see how Fubini's theorem produces this. Can anyone help to fill in the blank?

**EDIT:** Removed reference to the integrals evaluating to 1. I'm asking for an explanation of the measure theory setup behind the equality of the two integral expression that Dilip mentions in his comment below. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: On the left handside, you have a k-uple integral, whereas on the right handside, you have the product of $k$ simple integrals. Each of this integral on the right sums to 1 (I imagine they're densities), so you've proved that you had a positive measure that adds up to one, ie an other density.

Comment: @MattB. Sorry, I should've clarified. I get that part where the RHS term equals 1. It's the equality between the LHS and RHS which is confusing to me.

Comment: The Fubini comment is being used to explain how the multidimensional integral of a product happens to work out to be the product of the one-dimensional integrals, and not why each density integrates to $1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Exactly. I'm trying to get an explanation of what's going on there. Maybe it's too elementary, but any pointers would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that line is supposed to establish the whole proof. Also, I don't think the notation is completely accurate. Fubini's theorem says that the integral over the product space wrt a product measure can be represented by a series of **iterated** integrals, one over each measure individual measure:

$\int\limits_{(X\in \Omega_1) \times (Y\in \Omega_2)} f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{X}\left[\int_{Y} f(x,y) dy\right]dx$.

So the the theorem is about the operation of "integration" not about functions. However, since $\phi(y_i)$ only depends on one variable, the iterated integrals can be factored, since, for example $\phi(y_1)$ is a constant when we are integrating wrt $y_2$. Since we are taking a product of univariate functions, each of with are constants relative to each other (when integrating over a variable not in their arguemnt), we end up with a product of individual integrals.

They key is not just Fubini's theorem, but that the LHS is a product of univariate functions.

Comment: Oh, wow. That was obvious in hindsight. Thanks for clearing things up!